# Showing $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$ using implicit and log differentiation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

Hey guys I'm looking over my review sheet for an upcoming test and I'm having trouble with this problem. Apparently I'm supposed to use implicit differentiation and log differentiation, and I'm familiar with both—but I don't really know how to start with this one.

The problem is as follows, show that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$$

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You know that $$\lim_{m \to +\infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{m} \right)^m = e$$
I used $m$ instead of $n$ on purpose. We want to leave this limit in a way we can solve it. It suggest the substitution: $$\frac{x}{n} = \frac{1}{m}$$
It is obvious that $n \to +\infty \implies m \to +\infty$. This also gives that $n = mx$. So the limit becomes: $$\lim_{m \to +\infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{m} \right)^{mx} = \lim_{m \to +\infty} \left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{m} \right)^m\right)^x$$
Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $y=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ so that $\log y=n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)$. Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\log y=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)}{1/n}.$$ 
Using L'Hopital's Rule, this is 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{-\frac{x}{n^2}/\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)}{-1/n^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{n}}=x.$$
So $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y=x$, which means that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y=e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the limit exists, then because the $\log$ function is continuous, you can write:

$$\log\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+{x\over n}\right)$$

From here you can use the theorem that says if the continuous version of the limit exists, i.e. if you replace $n$ by $y$, then so does the regular version and they agree giving us cause to consider:

$$=\lim_{y\to\infty}y\log\left(1+{x\over y}\right)$$

Now using L'Hopital's rule, we get:

$$=\lim_{y\to\infty}-{{y\over y+x}\cdot(-xy^{-2}) \over y^{-2}}=x.$$

---

I'm not sure exactly how they want you to use implicit/logarithmic differentiation on this without some heavy machinery. Justifying differentiation switch with the limit is hard. I could see this as a *possible* alternative which uses both ideas, though a bit weird:  let your limit be $L$ (assuming it exists) and then:

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp n\left(\log\left(1+{x\over n}\right)\right)$$

by continuity of the exponential:

$$=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+{x\over n}\right)\right)$$

Then you want to compute the derivative of this. Letting the inner limit be $u(x)$ we can use implicit differentiation to compute the derivative, $L'$ of the limit to be:

$$=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+{x\over n}\right)\right)\cdot {d\over dx}\left(\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+{x\over n}\right)\right)\right)$$

From there you take log derivatives on the inside to give:

$$=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+{x\over n}\right)\right)\cdot \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n{1/n \over 1+{x\over n}}\right)$$

canceling the $1/n$ and the $n$ inside the limit, you get:

$$=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+{x\over n}\right)\right)$$

which is the original function. Since the function is it's own derivative, it must be of the form $f(x)=Ae^x$ for some constant, $A$. Then setting $x=0$ we get $A=1$.